# Can I replace my if-statements to save running time?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am currently trying to improve the speed of my program.

I was wondering whether it would help to replace all if-statements of the type:

```
bool a=1;
int b=0;
if(a){b++;}
```

with this:

```
bool a=1;
int b=0;

b+=a;
```

I am unsure whether the conversion from bool to int could be a problem time-wise.

Comment: It's possible, but it's not a good idea. First of all it will make the code much harder to read, understand and maintain. Secondly, the compiler is very good at optimizations and will very likely do "the right thing" to make the first piece of code optimal. Lastly, this is a very small micro-optimization that will have *very* little impact. First try to measure and profile to find the *big* bottle-necks and optimize those.

Comment: Compile, compare assembler listings. If different, profile and conclude.

Comment: Oh, and `bool a = 1;` just seems wrong. What's wrong with the "proper" `bool a = true;`? Concentrate on writing good, clean, nice, maintainable and *working* code first of all. Then if it's not "good enough" (and that usually *is* good enough) then measure and profile to find bottle-necks to optimize. And when optimizing, *add comments*, as optimizations tend to make code more complicated and harder to read and understand.

Comment: That change is very unlikely to make any measurable difference. If that particular bit is a problem, try to do it less often instead of doing it faster.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, that is what I am currently doing. My main time-consuming part consist only of a few if statements executed over a trillion times. At this point I was mainly wondering out of curiosity, since I am new to programming and have very little insight into how the commands are executed etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilers are allowed to assume that the underlying value of a `bool` isn't messed up, so optimizing compilers *can* avoid the branch.

If we look [at the generated code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EgHHJp) for this artificial test

```
int with_if_bool(bool a, int b) {
    if(a){b++;}
    return b;
}

int with_if_char(unsigned char a, int b) {
    if(a){b++;}
    return b;
}

int without_if(bool a, int b) {
    b += a;
    return b;
}
```

clang will exploit this fact and generate the exact same branchless code that sums `a` and `b` for the `bool` version, and instead generate actual comparisons with zero in the `unsigned char` case (although it's still branchless code):

```
with_if_bool(bool, int): # @with_if_bool(bool, int)
  lea eax, [rdi + rsi]
  ret
with_if_char(unsigned char, int): # @with_if_char(unsigned char, int)
  cmp dil, 1
  sbb esi, -1
  mov eax, esi
  ret
without_if(bool, int): # @without_if(bool, int)
  lea eax, [rdi + rsi]
  ret
```

gcc will instead treat `bool` just as if it was an `unsigned char`, without exploiting its properties, generating similar code as clang's `unsigned char` case.

```
with_if_bool(bool, int):
  mov eax, esi
  cmp dil, 1
  sbb eax, -1
  ret
with_if_char(unsigned char, int):
  mov eax, esi
  cmp dil, 1
  sbb eax, -1
  ret
without_if(bool, int):
  movzx edi, dil
  lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  ret
```

Finally, Visual C++ will treat the `bool` and the `unsigned char` versions equally, just as gcc, although with more naive codegen (it uses a conditional move instead of performing arithmetic with the flags register, which IIRC traditionally used to be less efficient, don't know for current machines).

```
a$ = 8
b$ = 16
int with_if_bool(bool,int) PROC ; with_if_bool, COMDAT
  test cl, cl
  lea eax, DWORD PTR [rdx+1]
  cmove eax, edx
  ret 0
int with_if_bool(bool,int) ENDP ; with_if_bool

a$ = 8
b$ = 16
int with_if_char(unsigned char,int) PROC ; with_if_char, COMDAT
  test cl, cl
  lea eax, DWORD PTR [rdx+1]
  cmove eax, edx
  ret 0
int with_if_char(unsigned char,int) ENDP ; with_if_char

a$ = 8
b$ = 16
int without_if(bool,int) PROC ; without_if, COMDAT
  movzx eax, cl
  add eax, edx
  ret 0
int without_if(bool,int) ENDP ; without_if
```

In all cases, no branches are generated; the only difference is that, on most compilers, some more complex code is generated that depends on a `cmp` or a `test`, creating a longer dependency chain.

That being said, I would worry about this kind of micro-optimization only if you actually run your code under a profiler, and the results point to this specific code (or to some tight loop that involve it); in general you should write sensible, semantically correct code and focus on using the correct algorithms/data structures. Micro-optimization comes later.

---

> In my program, this wouldn't work, as a is actually an operation of the type: `b+=(a==c)`

This should be even better for the optimizer, as it doesn't even have any doubt about where the `bool` is coming from - it can just decide straight from the flags register. [As you can see](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3Ln92g), here gcc produces quite similar code for the two cases, clang exactly the same, while VC++ as usual produces something that is more conditional-ish (a `cmov`) in the `if` case.

Answer (score 3):

One rule of thumb when programming is to not micro-optimise.

Another rule is to write clear code.

But in this case, another rule applies. If you are writing optimised code then avoid any code that can cause branches, as you can cause unwanted cpu pipeline dumps due to failed branch prediction.

Bear in mind also that there are not `bool` and `int` types as such in assembler: just registers, so you will probably find that all conversions will be optimised out. Therefore

```
b += a;
```

wins for me; it's also clearer.

Comment: Thank you. This branching was precisely what I was trying to avoid, as I only recently learned about it. I was just unsure whether the benefits would outweigh the drawbacks.

Comment: I agree with this, however, it can be argued that `a` should better be declared as an `int` instead.

Comment: @SirDarius: That would really depend on what else `a` does.

Comment: @SirDarius In my program, this wouldn't work, as a is actually an operation of the type:  b+=(a==c)